# How to set corner radius of imageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cornerradius

In Objective-C such line

```
self.mainImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(self.mainImageView.frame)/4.0f;
```

does its job, I tried it in Swift using analogy

```
self.mainImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(self.mainImageView.frame)/4.0
```

and it doesn't change anything, the corners are the same as before. Moreover, Xcode does not show any syntax errors. Does Swift support any other way to reach this goal? I checked some other threads here and usually it's getting done in Swift in the way showed above.

Comment: self.mainImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (self.mainImageView.frame)/2.0

Comment: "CGRect is not convertible to double"

Comment: self.mainImageView.layer.cornerRadius = (self.mainImageView.frame.size.height)/2.0 doesn't work as well

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Layer draws out of clip region, you need to set it to mask to bounds:

```
self.mainImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius):

> By default, the corner radius does not apply to the image in the
>   layer’s contents property; it applies only to the background color and
>   border of the layer. However, setting the masksToBounds property to
>   true causes the content to be clipped to the rounded corners

Comment: I missed that line, now works perfectly fine, thank you @DarthMike !

Comment: this answer is correct for roundcorner after get image from url and set to imageview

Comment: my guuuyyyy nice!

Answer (score 38):

There is one tiny difference in **Swift 3.0** and **Xcode8**

Whenever you want to apply corner radius to UIView, make sure you call 
`yourUIView.layoutIfNeeded()` before calling `cornerRadius`.

Otherwise, it will return the default value for UIView's height and width (1000.0) which will probably make your View disappear.

Always make sure that all effects that changes the size of UIView (Interface builder constraints etc) are applied before setting any layer properties.

**Example of UIView class implementation**

```
class BadgeView: UIView {

  override func awakeFromNib() {

    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2.0
    layer.masksToBounds = true

   }
 }
```

Comment: masksToBounds was also needed for me to get it to work after the update to Swift 3.0

Answer (score 28):

You can define border radius of any view providing an "User defined Runtime Attributes", providing key path "layer.cornerRadius" of type string and then the value of radius you need ;)
See attached images below:

[image: Configuring in XCode]

[image: Result in emulator]

Comment: This is a clean & simple solution

Answer (score 19):

try this

```
self.mainImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(self.mainImageView.frame)/4.0
self.mainImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 11):

Marked with `@IBInspectable` in swift (or IBInspectable in Objective-C), they are easily editable in Interface Builder’s attributes inspector panel.
You can directly set **borderWidth**,**cornerRadius**,**borderColor** in attributes inspector

```
extension UIView {

  @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {

   get{
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
    }
    set {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Border Color is not working. It returns black always.

Comment: @JoeSene layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor is wrong, just update it like this: layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor

Answer (score 7):

in swift 3 'CGRectGetWidth' has been replaced by property 'CGRect.width'

```
    view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.width/4.0
    view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3, Xcode 8, iOS 10

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.mainImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.mainImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
  self.mainImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Calling from the main thread helped me because I rounded `containerView` - which was a subview of my tableView cells - in the `willDisplay`  tableView delegate method. Without calling it from the main thread, the frame was wrong

Answer (score 5):

I created an `UIView` extension which allows to round specific corners :

```
import UIKit

enum RoundType {
    case top
    case none
    case bottom
    case both
}

extension UIView {

    func round(with type: RoundType, radius: CGFloat = 3.0) {
        var corners: UIRectCorner

        switch type {
        case .top:
            corners = [.topLeft, .topRight]
        case .none:
            corners = []
        case .bottom:
            corners = [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight]
        case .both:
            corners = [.allCorners]
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            self.layer.mask = mask
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import UIKit

class BorderImage: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 10.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Based on @DCDC's answer

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create an UIImageView subclass (I have tried it and it's working perfectly on iPhone 7 and XCode 8):

```
class CIRoundedImageView: UIImageView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

and then you can also set a border:

```
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
```