# how to implement the customize button with corner radius

Tags: swift

I implement facebook and google button but I can't set the corner radius for the button  here is my code

```
    @IBOutlet var fb_login_btn: FBSDKLoginButton! 
          fb_login_btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    @IBOutlet var google_login_btn: GIDSignInButton!
  google_login_btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```

How can I customize the button in swift3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - how to set corner radius of imageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861383/swift-how-to-set-corner-radius-of-imageview)

Comment: how can u say this duplicate i am not asking about FBSDKLoginButton

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, they both descend from `UIView` and so have the same layer properties. See [FBSDKButton.h](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/f7531a838a1ec3308721f335e801ac9f508feee4/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKButton.h). Google's SDK doesn't appear to be open-source, but the types can be inspected in Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to set `layer` property `masksToBounds` to `true` for `cornerRadius`.

```
fb_login_btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
fb_login_btn.layer.masksToBounds = true

google_login_btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
google_login_btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Thanks dude u save my time