# How to round Facebook Login UIImageView corners on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, uiview, uiimageview

I am having trouble making the user image have rounded corners. This is the Facebook login photo. I have tried "userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5"

```
func setupSubviews() {

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        view.addSubview(userImageView)
        view.addSubview(nameLabel)

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": userImageView]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-80-[v0]-80-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": loginButton]))

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-110-[v0(110)]-10-[v1(30)]-20-[v2(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": userImageView, "v1": nameLabel, "v2": loginButton]))

        loginButton.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861383/swift-how-to-set-corner-radius-of-imageview

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10 // change value according you
imgView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
userImageView.layer.maskToBounds = true
```

Comment: I have also tried that, sorry forgot to include it @Jagdeep